# .NET applications sometimes doesn’t work on Windows CE

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I write applications for Windowe ME and CE in
C# .NET 2.0.  Sometimes I’ve got problems because
applications don’t work on some navigation devices.
On Windowe ME it is not problem because .NET can be
installed from a cab, but on most Windows CE devices
it is impossible because after soft reset all changes
disappear. I found out that in most difficult cases
good solution is to put all dll-s belonging to .NET
installation cab in the folder where the application
runs and everything work well. However there are some
devices for example Navroad NR460 (Windows CE 5.0) on which none of .NET
applications work (it is funny because previous and next
version of that navigation works well). I didn’t found
on this device cgacutil.exe program.
Is this possible to force the device to run any .NET application without
installing the Windows again?
What should I try to do to check if running .NET a
applications is possible?
What conditions should be fulfilled to run easiest application
written even in .NET 1.0

Answer (score 0):

If cgacutil.exe is not on the device, .NET CF is not installed on it.
The Windows CE .NET CF 2.0 cab file is, on my machine, located here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\wce500\armv4i\NETCFv2.wce5.armv4i.cab

To read the .NET CF version on your device, you can use this registry key:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft.NETCompactFramework]

I am not sure if it exists if you don't have .NET CF installed on your device.
Officially, private installation of .NET CF will not work, but in some cases it surprisingly does.. I would not rely on it though.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a Windows CE 5 device that did not run my Standard SDK 500 apps compiled with VS 2008. The root cause was that the device somes with the ancient Windows CE 5.00 whereas Visual Studio compiles with Major/Minor Version number of 5.01 (the so called subsystem version number). After I changed the Linker Command Line option to subsystem:5.00, the same app was able to run on this device. But that is all for C/C++ apps.

Cab files can also be restricetd to install only for platform versions in between a lower and high limit. For example require at least version 5.01 and max 5.99. This will not run on Windows CE 5.00 nor on Windows CE 6.

The other thing with runtimes is that they are written against a processor architecture, mostly ARM/XScale. But there are Windows CE 5 devices that run x86 or other processors. Cab files can also be restricetd to run only on certain processor types, so you can not install a cab set for Arm on a device running an x86 or sh4 processor.